# WorksheetFunction.Match Cannot Paste/Run

Tags: vba, excel

I recently upgraded my work Microsoft account from Excel 2010 to Excel 2016.

While I still had Excel 2010, I coded a series of Macros to automate a substantially tedious task. Upon moving to Excel 2016, one of my VBA scripts appears to have "broken".

Below is the script:

```
Sub RunMacro()

Sheets("Control1").Select

'Step 1: #Script searches for header matches in Control1 dataset, then will copy in next
'step to Data list

    With Sheets("Control1")

        Route_Name = WorksheetFunction.Match("ROUTE_NAME", Rows("1:1"), 0)
        Feature_Type = WorksheetFunction.Match("FEATURE_TYPE", Rows("1:1"), 0)
        Shape_Length = WorksheetFunction.Match("SHAPE_LENGTH", Rows("1:1"), 0)


'Step 2: #Data transfer process

        Sheets("Control1").Columns(Route_Name).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("A7")
        Sheets("Control1").Columns(Feature_Type).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("B7")
        Sheets("Control1").Columns(Shape_Length).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("T7")

    End With

End Sub
```

When I run the script, I receive a Run-time error '1004', stating: "You can't paste this here because the Copy area and paste area aren't the same size. Select just one cell in the paste area or an area that's the same size and try pasting again."

The difficulty is, this script has no problem running in Excel/VBA 2010. What problems might exist with this script, or alternatively, are there potential macro security settings limiting this from functioning properly?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: the full column has 1048576 cells, you are trying to paste it starting in row 7.  From 7 to bottom of the sheet only has 1048569 cells.  so it cannot be pasted.

Comment: I dont see how this would work on any version, you're trying to copy a whole column (e.g.. all cells possible in a column) into a cell in that column. Of course there aren't enough rows. Try Sheets("Control1").Columns(Route_Name).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Columns(1), or whatever column is appropriate

Comment: Gentleman, I think you are absolutely right. How might I go about fixing that? I just realized prior i had the data pasting into R1C1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always declare your variables:

```
Dim Route_Name As Long
Dim Feature_Type As Long
Dim Shape_Length As Long
```

You are not using the With Block you set up.  You need to precede any ranges that use that parent with `.`

```
.Rows("1:1")
```

Use Intersect to only copy the area that is used:

```
Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(Route_Name)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("A7")
```

So:

```
Sub RunMacro()

Dim Route_Name As Long
Dim Feature_Type As Long
Dim Shape_Length As Long

'Step 1: #Script searches for header matches in Control1 dataset, then will copy in next
'step to Data list

    With Sheets("Control1")

        Route_Name = WorksheetFunction.Match("ROUTE_NAME", .Rows("1:1"), 0)
        Feature_Type = WorksheetFunction.Match("FEATURE_TYPE", .Rows("1:1"), 0)
        Shape_Length = WorksheetFunction.Match("SHAPE_LENGTH", .Rows("1:1"), 0)


'Step 2: #Data transfer process


        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(Route_Name)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("A7")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(Feature_Type)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("B7")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(Shape_Length)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("T7")

    End With

End Sub
```

---

One more note:

This will fail if any of the lookups do not exist in the the first row.  There are many methods of capturing and dealing with this problem.

I like to use `On Error Resume Next` with an immediate `On Error Goto 0` This will then skip the error on those three lines only.  The `If`s will then only copy if the column was found:

```
Sub RunMacro()

Dim Route_Name As Long
Dim Feature_Type As Long
Dim Shape_Length As Long

'Step 1: #Script searches for header matches in Control1 dataset, then will copy in next
'step to Data list

    With Sheets("Control1")
        On Error Resume Next
            Route_Name = WorksheetFunction.Match("ROUTE_NAME", .Rows("1:1"), 0)
            Feature_Type = WorksheetFunction.Match("FEATURE_TYPE", .Rows("1:1"), 0)
            Shape_Length = WorksheetFunction.Match("SHAPE_LENGTH", .Rows("1:1"), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0

'Step 2: #Data transfer process

        If Route_Name Then _
            Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(Route_Name)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("A7")
        If Feature_Type Then _
            Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(Feature_Type)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("B7")
        If Shape_Length Then _
            Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(Shape_Length)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("T7")

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Scott, this works fantastic. Thank you so much for the help and guidance here.